How do I use a for loop with an if statement to only output array fields that only have values entered?
I have a Google form that stores reponses in a Google Sheet.  When the form is submitted a email is generated using the stored values in the sheet.  The body of the email will include all required fields from the form and only non-required fields that have been filled in.
I am trying to use a for loop to iterate over the array and use an if statement to only output fields that have data in them.  I am having a problem where it seems the for loop is not being entered.  I have added an else statement to check if the for loop is working but I am not getting any output.
I have added comments to my code to make it clear what the code is doing (or should be doing) in each section.
I can usually figure things out on my own by searching online but I have spent many hours searching online and cannot find a solution.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
function main() {
  
  // access the sheet with the form responses
    var formResponses = getSheetById(1693762938);

  // collect the data from the responses sheet
    var formData = formResponses.getRange(1, 1, formResponses.getLastRow(), formResponses.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();

  // collect questions
    var formQuestions = formResponses.getRange(1, 2, 1, formResponses.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValue();

  // collect the responses
    var recentResponse = formResponses.getRange(formResponses.getLastRow(), 2, 1, formResponses.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  
  // only output answers with values
    recentResponse.filter(Boolean).forEach(function(value) {
    var filterData = value.filter(String);
      Logger.log(recentResponse);
      Logger.log([filterData]);

  // email receipient  (Required Form Fields)
    var businessName = Logger.log(recentResponse[0][0])
    var receiptEmail = Logger.log(recentResponse[0][1])
    var receipientName = Logger.log(recentResponse[0][2])
    var receipientAddress = Logger.log(recentResponse[0][3])
    var shippingMethod = Logger.log(recentResponse[0][4])

  // example of outputting null index values
    var orderedItem = Logger.log(recentResponse[0][5] + "," + "Qty =" + " " + (recentResponse[0][6]));
  
  // example of outputting of index with values
    var orderedItem = Logger.log(recentResponse[0][7] + "," + "Qty =" + " " + (recentResponse[0][8]));

  // another example of outputing null index values
    var orderedItem = Logger.log(recentResponse[0][9] + "," + "Qty =" + " " + (recentResponse[0][10]));
  
  // trying to use a for loop to only output fields with data startng with index [0][5]
    for (var i = 5; i < filterData[0][i]; i++){
       if (filterData[0][i] !== ''){
        Logger.log(filterData[0][i] + "," + "Qty =" + " " + (filterData[0][i+1]));
      } else {
        Logger.log("no entry");
      }
    }

getSheetById - Script
function getSheetById(sheet_id) {

  // acessing the workbook
    var wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // access all the sheets in the workbook
    var sheets = wb.getSheets();

  // loop through the sheets variable
    for(i in sheets){
      // if the sheet id matches the sheet argument
      if(sheets[i].getSheetId() == sheet_id) {
        //store the sheet name
          var sheetName = sheets[i].getSheetName();
      }
    }

  // return the wb sheet name
    return wb.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  
}

email.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello <?= receipientName ?>,</p>
    <p></p>
    <p>A new order for <b><?= businessName ?></b> has been submitted by <?= submitterEmail ?> Please use <b>"REPLY ALL"</b> and reply with "I approve this order" and your order will be placed. Please verify your shipping address below before approving your order.</p>
     <p><b><?= 'Equipment Ordered:' ?></b></p>
      <p><? var data = itemsToEmail;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
      <b><?= data[i] ?><br></b>
    <? } ?></p>
    <p></p>
    <p><b><i>**Shipping charges and applicable sales tax will also be applied for hardware orders. If only an order for remote (Oneline) training, please disregard shipping instructions.</i></b></p>
    <p></p>
    <p><b>Hardware will be shipped (if applicable) to:</b></p>
    <p></p>
    <p><?= receipientAddress ?></p>
    <p><b>Shipping Method:</b></p>
    <p><?= shippingMethod ?></p>
  </body>
</html>

Here are the log output
9:50:47 PM  Notice  Execution started
9:50:56 PM  Info    [[Happy Days Cafe, myname@gmail.com, First Last, 123 Hillbilly Drive, Pick up, , , Apple Pie, 1, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , Half Baked, ]]
9:50:56 PM  Info    [[Happy Days Cafe, myname@gmail.com, First Last, 123 Hillbilly Drive, Pick up, Apple Pie, 1, Half Baked]]
9:50:56 PM  Info    Happy Days Cafe
9:50:56 PM  Info    myname@gmail.com
9:50:56 PM  Info    First Last
9:50:56 PM  Info    123 Hillbilly Drive
9:50:56 PM  Info    Pick up
9:50:56 PM  Info    ,Qty = 
9:50:56 PM  Info    Apple Pie,Qty = 1
9:50:56 PM  Info    ,Qty = 
9:50:49 PM  Notice  Execution completed



Where is the corresponding closing } for forEach(function(value) { ?  2. Where is the corresponding closing " for "no entry); ?


Yes I had a type-o and missed adding " but that is not my issue. I am not missing any }.  I am having issues working with my array in parsing out only those indexes that have values. Any help would be greatly appreciated

It's really difficult to understand your code. All the lines after forEach have no indentation, which they should have if they're part of the forEach callback, and there's no closing of the forEach scope. So are those lines part of the forEach callback or not? Also, how is filterData relevant? You're not using it anywhere in the code we can see.

@Lennholm Thank  you for your reply.  That block of code you mention with the forEach is working fine.  As you can see from the log output the array does not contain any empty members as in the first output line.  The for loop at the bottom of the code is where I am trying to output each member of the array on a separate line but not include the array members that are undefined.  I want to dynamically loop through the array and only output array indexes with values.  I have tried using the filterData array in my for loop but I will update the block with this array.

From what I can tell, filterData is an array of strings, which means your for statement is incorrect. It should be like this: for (var i = 5; i < filterData.length; i++) and inside the for block, filterData[0] should be simply filterData, so e.g. filterData[0][i] becomes filterData[i].

There are 5 {, but only 3 }. This is not the issue, but your code should be pasted without syntax errors to be reproducible and for others to look into the actual issue. We can't just gloss over the basics.

I have updated the code above that I am using to loop through and produce the results I need for the email  body.  Thank you for all those that helped with this.

@JoeCoyle If you are not looking for an answer anymore and you think that this question will not be helpful for anyone else, please delete it. However, if you think that the solution that you found will be helpful for others, instead of editing the question, the solution should be added as an answer.

getSheetById is undefined

What kind of object is f0rmResponses?

@Wicket Thank you for the advice.  I did not think I could answer my own question.

@Cooper the getSheetById is defined under the getSheetByID script.  I will update the question with this script.  I will also add the code for email.html.  formRespones is a var that holds the ID of the Google sheet that stores the form responses.

Try running this and let me know what you get?
function main(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
}


Here is the final solution that works for what I was trying to accomplish.  Thank you for all those that added comments.
code.gs
function main() {
  
    // access the sheet with the form responses
    var formResponses = getSheetById(1693762938);

    // collect the data from the responses sheet
    var formData = formResponses.getRange(1, 1, formResponses.getLastRow(), formResponses.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();

    // collect the responses
    var recentResponse = formResponses.getRange(formResponses.getLastRow(), 2, 1, formResponses.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();

    // only output answers with values
    recentResponse.filter(Boolean).forEach(function(allFormValues) {
      var filterData = allFormValues.filter(String);

    // crate a template object for dynamcally contructing html
    var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('email');

    // email receipient information  (Required Form Fields)
    htmlTemplate.receipientName = filterData[2];
    htmlTemplate.businessName = filterData[0];
    htmlTemplate.receiptEmail = filterData[1];
    htmlTemplate.receipientAddress = filterData[3];
    htmlTemplate.shippingMethod = filterData[4];

    // loop through non-required fields startng with index [0][5] and filter the results
    htmlTemplate.itemsToEmail = [];
    var i = 5;
    for (n, i; i < filterData.length; i++){
      if (filterData[i] !== 0 && filterData[i+1] !== 0 && filterData[i+1] !== undefined){

        // concatenate equipment ordered with quantity and create an array of ordered items for email
        htmlTemplate.itemsToEmail.push(filterData[i] + ","+ " " + "Qty =" + filterData[i+1]);
          i++
        } else if (filterData[i+1] == undefined) {

          // catch the notes response if any and do not add Qty string
          htmlTemplate.itemsToEmail.push(filterData[i]);
          i++
        };

      // capture the form submitter email address
      htmlTemplate.submitterEmail = (Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());

      // evaluate the template and return html output
        var htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();

      };

    // send the email
    GmailApp.sendEmail(htmlTemplate.receiptEmail, 
    "Tend Hardware Order - ACTION REQUIRED", 
    "This email contains html", 
    {htmlBody: htmlForEmail, cc: 'email1@domain.com, email2@domain.com'}
    );

  });
};

getSheetByID.gs
function getSheetById(sheet_id) {

  // accessing the workbook
    var wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // access all the sheets in the workbook
    var sheets = wb.getSheets();

  // loop through the sheets variable
    for(i in sheets){
      // if the sheet id matches the sheet argument
      if(sheets[i].getSheetId() == sheet_id) {
        //store the sheet name
          var sheetName = sheets[i].getSheetName();
      }
    }

  // return the wb sheet name
    return wb.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  
}

email.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello <?= receipientName ?>,</p>
    <p></p>
    <p>A new order for <b><?= businessName ?></b> has been submitted by <?= submitterEmail ?> Please use <b>"REPLY ALL"</b> and reply with "I approve this order" and your order will be placed. Please verify your shipping address below before approving your order.</p>
     <p><b><?= 'Equipment Ordered:' ?></b></p>
      <p><? var data = itemsToEmail;
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
      <b><?= data[i] ?><br></b>
    <? } ?></p>
    <p></p>
    <p><b><i>**Shipping charges and applicable sales tax will also be applied for hardware orders. If only an order for remote (Oneline) training, please disregard shipping instructions.</i></b></p>
    <p></p>
    <p><b>Hardware will be shipped (if applicable) to:</b></p>
    <p></p>
    <p><?= receipientAddress ?></p>
    <p><b>Shipping Method:</b></p>
    <p><?= shippingMethod ?></p>
  </body>
</html>

